# SharedPreferences for checking the logged in value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app which has an login system and depending on that the app starts another activity if it is logged in. Can anyone help me with that code. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

after successfull login, save logged in user data in SharedPreferences

```
//save login data
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = mContext.getSharedPreferences("datas",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
spe.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
spe.commit();
```

and load data from SharedPreferences where you want to check if user logged in.

```
//Load login data
SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("datas",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sp.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)==true) {
//user is logged in
        } else {
//user is not logged in
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do sometimes, I have my default MainActivity that always run initially.

Then in onCreate I have a check to decide which activity to start:

```
boolean isLoggedIn = checkUserStatus();
Intent intent = isLoggedIn ? new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class) 
                           : new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`checkUserStatus()` is a simple function which get a boolean flag to determine if the user was logged in or not:

```
protected boolean checkUserStatus(){
    boolean isLoggedIn ;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    isLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
    return isLoggedIn ;
}
```

then set the `boolean` to true or false :

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);// or false if you log out
edit.commit();
```